# C++ "namespace scope"

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern, specifications

The C++ spec (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf, section 7.5.4) states that

> A linkage-speciﬁcation shall occur only in namespace scope

What exactly does "namespace scope" mean? Does this mean that a linkage-specification, such as `extern "C"` can't be in global scope, only in a namespace?
What exactly does "namespace scope" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means, that `extern "C"` should be only in namespace-scope (not class-scope, block-scope etc.) Something, that is not in namespace, but is in global scope - is in global namespace scope.

> The potential scope denoted by
> an original-namespace-name is the concatenation of the declarative regions established by each of the
> namespace-definitions in the same declarative region with that original-namespace-name.